# What does this question, regarding the balance of 5E Moon Druids, need to fit on RPG.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic, dnd-5e

I have a concern:

> ### Opinions
>
> Moon Druids are considered too powerful at low levels.  Often times,
>   Moon Druids have no need to spend any spell slots to accomplish their
>   goals, and don't need any other features from being a
>   Druid to play their character.
>
> In essence, being a Moon Druid effectively makes being a base-class
>   Druid obsolete.
>
> I believe that Druids, like other classes, should utilize roughly all
>   of their resources by the time they get refreshed, which includes
>   Spell Slots by the end of the day.

I understand that there may not be experience with homebrews addressing this exact scenario, but some of this can be backed by some numbers analysis, experience with Moon Druids being able to ignore utilizing spell slots (or not), and gauging when other classes run out of resources (to come up with a budget of when the Druid should run out).

---

My question is, how do I ask how big of a balance concern the existing rules are in 5E for this specific issue (5E Moon Druids and their balance vs. other classes), and how do I request a fix that addresses this concern?

Comment: Is my summary of your two approaches you're highlighting at the bottom accurate? It sounds from your comment on my answer like it is not accurate, but I am not sure what I'm misunderstanding in that case. Instead of describing it as "threads" collecting analysis and "regarding" stuff, can you clearly say what you'll be asking in what questions?

Comment: @doppelgreener Sorry, I kept that little section at the end to not make your answer obsolete.  Really, my concern is the small section directly replacing them.  How do I ask how unbalanced a particular part of the 5E game is, and how should I ask how to fix it?

Comment: Ok. I've posted a new answer, though it's fundamentally the same course of action the original recommended.

Comment: The "fix" is to play past level 6.

Answer (score 12):

Do it in two parts:

1. In one question, explain the problem you're seeing with the moon druid. Ask if you're understanding how it works correctly, and ask if this is a major problem like you understand it to be. You can/should say you're concerned this makes the base druid obsolete and ask if that seems more or less accurate.

Answers will corroborate or correct your (mis?)understanding. They will clarify what needs clarification, and explain or confirm what's going on. They will also convey how much of a problem this is.

The voting community will then sort some of the answers to the top. Those top answers represent what the voting community here believes is the actual scope and scale of the problem (including, possibly, no problem at all).

Then, a few days later once the dust has settled, we'll understand what the actual problem is. *Then* we can ask how to resolve it. Thus the second question:

2. In a second question, summarise the problem as validated by the community. Link back to the original question from step 1. Ask people how to resolve the balance issue. Prompt them to cite experience on how the fix has worked in practice.

How to ask this exactly depends on what the balance issue is. If it's "the moon druid has free unlimited resources", ask how to constrain their resources in line with the original druid. If they're just superior in every way to the original druid, ask how to bring them back in line with the original druid.

The prompt for experience is a gentle reminder to follow our good subjective citations: people can *guess* at fixes from their seats all they want, but we're looking for fixes that verifiably work.

Right now I don't think we have meta guidance on how we handle asking for this kind of fix, so if you're not sure how you'd word this request, just focus on step 1 for now and come back to meta for assistance when it's time for step 2.